# How to retain the value of a variable after sucessive submission of form

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I am developing a Contextual Search Engine in php. For that when an user types a query, I need her latlong and time. I am developing the search box in php. To get latlong I am using HTML 5 geolocation api. I have written following two files by taking idea from posts in stackoverflow.

order.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getLocation(){
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  if (navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position){
  var latitude=document.getElementById("latitude"),
      longitude=document.getElementById("longitude");
  latitude.value = position.coords.latitude;
  longitude.value = position.coords.longitude;
}

</script>

</head>
<body onload="getLocation()">

<p id="demo"></p>
<form id="searchbox" action="process.php" method="get">
  <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Type here">
  <input name="latitude" id="latitude" type="hidden">
  <input name="longitude" id="longitude" type="hidden">
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
</body></html>
```

Another file is process.php

```
<html>
<body>
  <form id="searchbox" action="process.php" method="post">
   <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Type here">
   <input name="latitude" id="latitude" type="hidden" value="<?php $latitude=$_POST['latitude']; echo $latitude; ?>">
   <input name="longitude" id="longitude" type="hidden" value="<?php $longitude=$_POST['longitude'];echo $longitude; ?>">
   <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search">
 </form>

<?php $quantity=$_POST['quantity'];
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$arr=explode(" ",$date);
$latitude=$_GET['latitude'];
$longitude=$_GET['longitude'];
echo "Latitude=". $latitude."Longitude=". $longitude." Time=".$arr[1]."<br>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that whenever I am submitting the form again from process.php the latitude and longitude values are getting reset. So how do I retain the value of them that I have got after landing on process.php so that they do not get reset even if I submit the form from process.php multiple times.

In this context I have seen other similar questions asked here and applied their solutions but none of them seems to be working. So please help. Thank you.

Comment: Can you not attach the long/lat data values to your REQUEST headers? Then you would be able to access the values on the serverside

Comment: Sir, sorry I did not understand. I am new to php. I don't know what is REQUEST header. So could you please explain? Thank you.

Comment: See the answer SULEMAN and STEGREX has written below? that is what i mean, but i too lack php knowledge. It looks like STEGREX is the better of the two answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside process.php, you're using GET in order to get the value that's being POSTed from a process.php form submission.

You can change:

```
$latitude=$_GET['latitude'];
$longitude=$_GET['longitude'];
```

Into

```
$latitude=$_REQUEST['latitude'];
$longitude=$_REQUEST['longitude'];
```

`$_REQUEST` basically contains both GET and POSTs (to be safe, make sure there are no conflicting get/post params with the same key name).

Answer (score 0):

You are submitting the first form via the GET method which puts the values in the URL and the second form on the process.php page uses the POST method which puts the values in the body of the request and not the URL.

You are then getting lat and long from the `$_GET` super global which no longer holds lat and long as they are now in the `$_POST` superglobal.

You should use either GET or POST consistently, and for a search engine, I'd recommend GET so that users can pass around links to results (you can't bookmark a POST'ed page).

Comment: I have changed the method from POST to GET and made other changes to the variables in input of the form accordingly in process.php. But even after that, it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the Geolocation values in the POST request when in fact the initial form is sending the values as a GET request.

Change in `process.php` the following lines:

```
<input name="latitude" id="latitude" type="hidden" value="<?php $latitude=$_POST['latitude']; echo $latitude; ?>">
<input name="longitude" id="longitude" type="hidden" value="<?php $longitude=$_POST['longitude'];echo $longitude; ?>">
```

to

```
<input name="latitude" id="latitude" type="hidden" value="<?php $latitude=$_REQUEST['latitude']; echo $latitude; ?>">
<input name="longitude" id="longitude" type="hidden" value="<?php $longitude=$_REQUEST['longitude'];echo $longitude; ?>">
```